# Render looks like there are weird artifacts on the walls

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I created this scene and it was ready for rendering. I am using cycles as my render engine. In viewport, my max samples is 100 and is starts in 50. My noise threshold and denoise is turned on as well. It was looking okay at first but it somehow looked like this now in viewport and even in the final render.

[image]

I tried solving this issue by turning off the noise threshold in viewport and it looked normal and the weird artifacts something on the plate and walls were gone.

I wanna know if this is about the noise threshold and how can I fix this? Or is this somehow connected to my materials that include transmission? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a combination of the noise threshold and the Optix denoiser (the Automatic one).
If you try the OpenImage denoiser for example, you'll see that you get a different result.

In the Render where you have much more samples and if you lower the noise threshold, you won't get that issue.